# My div borders getting cut off when I print the document

Tags: html, css, printing

I am creating a section for employees to put their initials using HTML and CSS. I can't figure out why the borders of my `initial-box`'s are getting cut off.

Here is the html

```css
#initials {
  padding: 0px;
}

.initial-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="initials">
  <table id="initial-table">
    <tr class="initial-labels">
      <td>1st shift</td>
      <td>2nd shift</td>
      <td>3rd shift</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="initial-box"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="initial-box"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="initial-box"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is the result
[image: Here is the result]

Comment: Based on the code you posted they're not

Comment: I just realized that by trying it out in a js fiddle. gonna have to dig deeper and see whats going on.

Comment: @j08691 I just discovered that this is only happening when I print the page/look at it in print preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to try to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.initial-box` to have the border width included in the height and width settings.

```css
#initials {
  padding: 0px;
}

.initial-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="initials">
  <table id="initial-table">
    <tr class="initial-labels">
      <td>1st shift</td>
      <td>2nd shift</td>
      <td>3rd shift</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="initial-box"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="initial-box"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="initial-box"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```